# driver find element if else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, web-scraping, web, browser

On here , My if else statement is not working
whenever i run the script
if "IF" condition matches , its working
if its matches "ELSE" condition , its not working

Here is the code

```
       if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='Close']"):
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='Close']").click()
        else:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='OK']")))
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='OK']").click()

       
        print((sh.cell(row=r,column=2).value), r)
        r = r + 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUYOD.png)

Comment: _if its matches "ELSE" condition , its not working_ What exactly do you mean "not working"?  Do you get an error?  Do you get other unexpected results?  Do you get no results at all?

Comment: in this script
if the close pop up appears in web page it should click "close" & move on
or
if the Ok pop up appears in web page it should click "Ok" & move on

while running if "close" pop up's its running normally
but if "ok" pop up's the script stops running & throws error like

 File "C:\Users\Desktop\test.py", line 62, in locate_by_id_demo
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='Unlock']"):

Comment: So this code is causing an error, and you didn't post that in the question?  Were we supposed to guess?

Comment: Could you pls help me to resolve the issue here John

Comment: Edit the question and post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is , When the element is not found, it throws  'NoSuchElementException'

so for the proper working

```js
try:

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='Close']").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='OK']")))

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='OK']").click()
print((sh.cell(row=r,column=2).value), r)
r = r + 1
In this code, the try-except block is used to handle exceptions that might occur
```

And also there is a another way which uses simple if else statement

```js
if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='Close']").is_displayed():
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='Close']").click()
else:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='OK']")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bdi[normalize-space()='OK']").click()

print((sh.cell(row=r,column=2).value), r)
r = r + 1

Note: I added the is_displayed() method to check if the element with the text "Close" is displayed on the page before attempting to click it.
```